# Logging propagation while using multiprocessing.Queue()

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

**I'm not sure whether I am doing something wrong or if I am just misunderstanding how logging is intended to work.**

**I'm trying to use logging while running an instance of `multiprocessing.Queue()`.  I set up a `root_logger` instance in my module inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block like so:**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    hndlr = logging.FileHandler(filename='root_logger.log', mode='w')
    root_logger.addHandler(hndlr)
    root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

**and grab a reference to the mutiprocessing logger via `multiprocessing.get_logger()`.**

**Then, inside my worker process, I set up another logger like so:**

```
from somemodule import somefunction

class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
    def _log_setup(self):
        '''Done outside of init to avoid trying to pickle the logging instance.'''
        #Create a unique logger
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('Worker_'+self.filename[0:13])
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        #Create a unique log file
        hndlr = logging.FileHandler(filename='./' + os.path.basename(self.filename) + '.log', mode='w')
        self.logger.addHandler(hndlr)
    def __call__(self):
        self._log_setup()
        self.logger.info('Logged from worker')
        somefunction(self.filename)
```

**where `somemodule.somefunction()` looks like this:**

```
def somefunction(filename):
    log.info('Doing something to %s' % filename)
```

#### What I'd like to see:

- The log file from `root_logger` (root_logger.log) should contain the output of anything executed in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.
- The log file from `root_logger` should also contain any output from the multiprocessing package.
- The unique worker log files (Worker_YYYYJJJHHMMSS.log) should contain all logging output from calls to `Worker.logger` as well as output from any calls (in this case, `somefunction()`)
- It would be preferable for the log file from `root_logger` to contain only output from calls to `Worker.logger.warning()` or higher, but this is not imperative.

#### What I currently see:

- The log file from `root_logger` **correctly** contains output from everything executed in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.
- The log file from `root_logger` **correctly** contains output from the logger instance returned by `multiprocessing.get_logger()`.
- The log file from `root_logger` **incorrectly** contains output from the logger instance contained in `somemodule.somefunction()`.
- The unique worker log files (Worker_YYYYJJJHHMMSS.log) **correctly** contains output from calls to `Worker.logger`.
- The worker file logs **incorrectly** do not contain output from calls to the logger instance in `somemodule.somefunction()`.

**Is it possible to modify the `logging` propagation flow in some way to achieve what I'm looking for here?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like everything is working except that the logging from `somemodule.somefunction()` is sending data to the wrong place.

You say that `somemodule.somefunction()` looks like

```
def somefunction(filename):
    log.info('Doing something to %s' % filename)
```

Since `log` is not defined in your function, I hope that it's defined at a module level.  That would mean that whatever logger is at the module level would be where the data is sent.  If your code is anything like mine, that module-level logger is set up to send data to the root logger.  You may need to pass in the specific logging instance (i.e. `Worker.logger`) and use that instead.